# How to detect and extract text from the kyc document using opencv python?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-tesseract, opencv

I have an image of aadhar card. I want to detect the text from the aadhar card . I have used the EAST text detection algorithm to detect the text but I counld not find the good result. Now I am trying the other method such as

1. convert the image into gray scale
2. apply threshold
3. find contours

   ```
   image11=cv2.imread('1.jpg')
   gray_image=cv2.cvtColor(image11, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   threshed=cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_image,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
                             cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
   ##  Morph-op to remove noise
   kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11,11))
   morphed = cv2.morphologyEx(threshed, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
   cnts = cv2.findContours(morphed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
   ```

But after finding the contours what is the next steps ? or any other method ? so that I detect the text? . Thanks

input Images:

[image]

Comment: You have `pytesseract` in your tags, so it seems you know what to do in general!? First of all, do you only want to extract the text from the three shown boxes? Do you only have this single image? Crop the boxes by hand and run `pytesseract` using `config='--psm 6'`, maybe twice, first using English, second using some Devanagari specific `traineddata`. If you want to extract those boxes from multiple images: Are all images perfectly aligned? Again, use hard-coded values for the boxes. For some more arbitrary images, provide more input examples.

Comment: On a side note: Are you allowed to provide personal data of people? That doesn't look like some "John Doe".

Comment: Yes, I have used the pytesseract to extract the data from the aadhar card but I can not get the good .I am not trying only these three boxes I want to extract all the english word such as name, number, DOB and Gender. I have many aadhar images . I want to only  ask that how to make the bounding boxes around the text such as aadhar card number (only one boxes)?

Comment: Or Please tell me any research paper related to the aadhar card text detection and extraction .

Comment: please check these links may be helpful [link1](https://github.com/dilippuri/Aadhaar-Card-OCR) [link2](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/aadhaar-pan-info-extraction-using-python-ocr-5df81b6c66e3)

Comment: okay, I check and apply on images

Comment: @gowridev Can you provide the research papers?

Comment: see these links [link1](https://www.ijert.org/research/ekyc-mobile-application-using-optical-character-recognition-IJERTV9IS020418.pdf) [link2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.03492.pdf) [link3](https://medium.com/swlh/document-verification-for-kyc-with-ai-ocr-computer-vision-tool-3485d85d75f6) [link4](https://github.com/festivitymishra/PyraDox)

Comment: okay, Thanks .I see this all links.

Comment: Hi @HansHirse , I have the pytesseract to extract the text and I got the text okay. but in aadhar card there are some hindi and english words. is it possible If I extract only english word . bacuase when I  extract the text all hindi word are converted into english and they extract.I do not want to extract the hindi word. code ..... text=pytesseract.image_to_string(input_image, lang='eng').Please tell me is it possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use following documentation you achive.

https://pypi.org/project/pan-aadhar-ocr/

```
from pan_aadhar_ocr import Pan_Info_Extractor, Aadhar_Info_Extractor
extractor = Aadhar_Info_Extractor()
result = extractor.info_extractor('full.jpg','full.jpg')
```